# What is the best tool to inspect the state and size of a user's session state in a ASP.Net 2.0 application

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-2.0

We'd like to inspect the state of a user's session state and predefined points during the flow of a legacy web application. We'd like to see which objects are currently present and what the total size is.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor some of the [asp.net session performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx)